# something wrong with jsonp data, How to get the data

Tags: javascript, vue.js

But it returns -403 why

[image]

but when I click that, It comes out this

[image]

how can I get the message

Comment: does the unnamed resource actually support JSONP? do you know what a 403 error is?

Comment: Provide your code as text, not as images.

Comment: export function getShows () {
  const url = 'https://api.bilibili.com/x/web-show/res/loc?'

  const data = Object.assign({}, {jsonp: 'jsonp'}, {
    pf: 7,
    id: 1695
  })

  return jsonp(url, data, {param: 'jsonpCallback'})
}

Comment: 403 ? means I can't get the resouce?  Is there any other way to get this data here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The HTTP 403 Forbidden client error status response code indicates that the server understood the request but refuses to authorize it.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/403). After one-line check with Fetch API the answer is: server is not handling Cross Origin Resource Sharing - making cross-origin AJAX is not possible. You can avoid it by using simple local HTTP server (e.g. in Python) to get data from server (e.g. with requests) and self-serve it (e.g. with Flask).
Check it in JS console:

```
fetch('https://api.bilibili.com/x/web-show/res/loc?jsonp=jsonp&pf=7&id=1695').then(r=>r.json()).then(json=>console.log(json))
```